# CSS style for curvy bubble chat

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I need to draw a triangle with rounded corners (for bubble chat) as seen below, I found a couple of solutions using transform:rotate, skew and scale

my questions are:

1. is it possible to create this shape without complex css 3 rules
2. performance wise, do transform:rotate, skew and scale matter or is it negligible? (lets say if have this shape 6 times at once on a mobile page)

[image]

Comment: You should definitely check this- https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/
 & http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/

Answer (score 0):

You could make the chat box with border-radius to get the rounded corners, and then add a :before element with a css background image for the triangle on the top. All standard, easy CSS.

Answer (score 0):

check with below code may help you.

```css
#chat{
  background-color : #4692F0;
  height : 50px;
  width : 300px;
  border-radius : 5px;
}
#chat:before{
      position: absolute;
content: "\f0d8";
display: inline-block;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
top: -8px;
transform: rotate(76deg);
color: #4692F0;
font-size: 35px;
left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="chat">
  
</div>
```